# Where is EjbClient.Jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb

When I create a Ejb project in Eclipse 3.7 using JBoss 5.0 application server, then it gives me an option of creating EjbClient jar. But after deploying the Ejb I cannot find EjbClient jar ? Where does it get stored ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you created an EAR File along with your project. The EJBClient.jar file is used to store client interfaces and classes.
Your EJBClient.jar file will be in your EAR Project.
For instance, in eclipse if your project is called TestProject, look inside the TestProjectEAR project, expand Deployment Descriptor > Bundled Libraries.
You should see your EJBClient.jar file in there.

So when your app is deployed on the server the EJBClient.jar will be sitting somewhere in your EAR File.

Hope this helps